# Are Unique CognitoUsers Created on Email/Password and Social Federation Sign-In for the Same Email?

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'd like to confirm if what I observed is correct with regards to [Amazon Cognito User Pools](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools.html) and Amplify, specially with the bold text:

> A user pool is a user directory in Amazon Cognito. With a user pool,
>   your users can sign in to your web or mobile app through Amazon
>   Cognito. Your users can also sign in through social identity providers
>   like Google, Facebook, Amazon, or Apple, and through SAML identity
>   providers. **Whether your users sign in directly or through a third**
>   **party, all members of the user pool have a directory profile that you**
>   **can access through a Software Development Kit (SDK).**

**So far I have set-up in an amplify app:**

1. Email/Password Sign-up/Sign-in (used `amplify add auth` with username as email)
2. Google and Facebook social federation (used `amplify update auth`)

**What I Expect:**

1. I'll be able to create a new account (`CognitoUser`) with email `myemail@gmail.com` using **email/password** sign-up. (`myemail@gmail.com` hasn't been registered yet or associated with any social federation sign-ins).
2. A new `CognitoUser` account will not be created if I **Google Sign-in** using the Google email `myemail@gmail.com`. Instead, I will be presented with the account/CognitoUser that I confirmed from #1 after Google sign-in.

   > *Whether your users sign in directly or through a third party, all*
   >   *members of the user pool have a directory profile that you can access*
   >   *through a Software Development Kit (SDK).*

**What I Get/Observations:**

I seem to get (2) unique Cognito Users each for the email/password sign-in and Google Sign-in methods. *(Please see the attached **CognitoUser Logs** screenshots below)*

**My Questions:**

1. If I first signed-up an email (`myemail@gmail.com`) using email/password, do I get (2) unique Cognito Users if I sign-in again using a Google (or Facebook account) that uses the same email `myemail@gmail.com`?
2. If (2) CognitoUsers are created for the same email,

   1. How do I prevent a new CognitoUser creation for Google Sign-in when the email has already been registered using email/password and vice-versa?
   2. Is it possible to reuse the CognitoUser from an email/password sign-in on a Google sign-in of the same email?
   3. If [2.1] cannot be prevented, how can serverside data be best managed for the 2 CognitoUsers (that share the same email `myemail@gmail.com`)

TIA for your insights and advice!

**CognitoUser Logs**

1. **CognitoUser** from email/password sign-in (`myemail@gmail.com`):
   [image]
2. **CognitoUser** from Google Sign-in (`Auth.federatedSignIn({provider: 'Google'})`). Google email is `myemail@gmail.com`:
   [image: CognitoUser - Google Signin]

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: Have you found  a solution to this? If yes, please share. Thanks!

Comment: @ian, Azher Aleem  I solved this issue by linking users in the Cognito pre-signup hook as advised by hakimio on this thread https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/369. However there are still issues for facebook, as weaponsforge mentioned on the last comments